# flask sqlalchemy unique constraint not working

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, unique-constraint, nonetype

I am going through Miguel's awesome flask web development book. I have a question regarding the models.

This is my User model

```
class User(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'users'
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
   role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))

   def __repr__(self):
       return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

In the model, its mentioned that 'username' field is unique, which means this column should have unique values.

Yet i have entries in User model that have the same values.

Here is the snippet from the shell session.

```
for user in User.query.all():
    print user.username
```

output:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

I want to know why it allowed to create entries with `username=None` multiple times?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add clause `nullable=False` to your `username` column declaration:

```
username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
```

DB doesn't take `None` as a value.